# show the reminder notification while running process in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i  have to show the popup window when its match with database time and date value .but that popup window have to show on even the project is on running process
 i have put the reminder c# code in master page but it only show notification window while application on any event or have to reload the page i want to show the without reloading the page

1. i have to run my c# code background
2. if my C# code match with database value automatically trigger the reminder popup 
   3.could i do this process using window or web service in asp.net c#